# ViewFlipper auto-flipping Not Working

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have write a Simple code of `ViewFlipper` i want the view's to be auto flipped and declared interval as `viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(1000)` but it's not working. Here is my code. please help me where i am wrong.

```
 viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(1000);
            int[] resources = {
              R.drawable.image1,
              R.drawable.image2,
              R.drawable.image3,

      };

      for (int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
          imageView.setImageResource(resources[i]);
          viewFlipper.addView(imageView,i);
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have never called `startFlipping()` on your `ViewFlipper`

do:

```
viewFlipper.startFlipping();
```

see [ViewFlipper#startFlipping();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html#startFlipping())

Answer (score 3):

Setting an auto flip timer will create a slideshow and can be controlled by **startFlipping()** and **stopFlipping()** method.

add this code

```
 viewFlipper.startFlipping();
```